# Enabling EditText when a radiobutton is checked

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to keep an `EditText` disabled until a specific `RadioButton` is checked. This is the piece of code:

```
    val EditText = binding.customPercent
   when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        R.id.option_fifteen_percent -> EditText.isFocusable = false
        R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> EditText.isFocusable = false
        R.id.option_twenty_percent -> EditText.isFocusable = false
        else -> EditText.isFocusable = true
    }
```

And this is my entire code if needed:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener{ calculateTip()}
    binding.costOfServiceEditText.setOnKeyListener { view, keyCode, _ -> handleKeyEvent(view, keyCode) }

}



private fun calculateTip(){
    val stringInTextField = binding.costOfServiceEditText.text.toString()
    val cost = stringInTextField.toDoubleOrNull()



   if (cost == null){
        binding.tipResult.text = ""
        binding.costOfService.hint = "Insira o valor aqui"
        return
    }

    val customPercent = binding.customPercent.getText().toString().toDouble()
    val customPercentOption = customPercent / 100

    val tipPercentage = when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
        R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
        R.id.option_fifteen_percent -> 0.15
        else -> customPercentOption

    }

    val EditText = binding.customPercent
   when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        R.id.option_fifteen_percent -> EditText.isFocusable = false
        R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> EditText.isFocusable = false
        R.id.option_twenty_percent -> EditText.isFocusable = false
        else -> EditText.isFocusable = true
    }


    var tip = tipPercentage * cost
    val roundUp = binding.roundUpSwitch.isChecked
    if (roundUp) {
        tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
    }

    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
    val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
    binding.tipResult.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)

}
```

I'm new to programming so I'm sorry if it is a dumb question
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a RadioButton listener outside you calculateTip() method, see the following code:

```
MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener{ calculateTip()}
    binding.costOfServiceEditText.setOnKeyListener { view, keyCode, _ -> handleKeyEvent(view, keyCode) }
    
    //adding listener and manipulate editText
    val EditText = binding.customPercent
    radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
                when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
                R.id.option_fifteen_percent -> EditText.isEnabled = false
                R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> EditText.isEnabled = false
                R.id.option_twenty_percent -> EditText.isEnabled = false
                else -> EditText.isEnabled = true }
         }
      )
   }

private fun calculateTip(){
val stringInTextField = binding.costOfServiceEditText.text.toString()
val cost = stringInTextField.toDoubleOrNull()



if (cost == null){
    binding.tipResult.text = ""
    binding.costOfService.hint = "Insira o valor aqui"
    return
}

val customPercent = binding.customPercent.getText().toString().toDouble()
val customPercentOption = customPercent / 100

val tipPercentage = when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
    R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
    R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
    R.id.option_fifteen_percent -> 0.15
    else -> customPercentOption

}

var tip = tipPercentage * cost
val roundUp = binding.roundUpSwitch.isChecked
if (roundUp) {
    tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
}

NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
    val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
    binding.tipResult.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)

}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that the code is inside the calculateTip function

Comment: The code you sent it's actually working only when I press the calculateTip button, but I can't make it work outside this function

Comment: I guess I know what is happening. You have to create a listener for the Radio buttons and handle EditText outside this calculateTip function. Im going to update my answer

Comment: Okay!! Thank you very much

Comment: How can I create this listener? I'm trying but no success so far

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I'll just try to understand how it worked haha ;) Maybe study this OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Oh, I needed to change the isFocusable from the code you suggested to isEnabled. The same way you said before ;)

Comment: Yeeesss im sorry I copied/pasted your code I totally forgot about that. Im glad the code works, cheers!